morphing string to date in arktype
I'm trying to to use the new Temporal date API in JavaScript and while trying to write a type using arktype library that takes in a string and morphs it into a Temporal zoned date time.
Example:
import { Temporal } from '@js-temporal/polyfill';
import { type } from 'arktype';

const dateSchema = type("string").pipe((str: string) => Temporal.ZonedDateTime.from(str));

type DateParse = typeof dateSchema.infer;

const dateParse: DateParse = Temporal.Now.zonedDateTimeISO().toString();

Error:
Type 'string' is not assignable to type { readonly era: string | undefined; ...
The expected result is that the dateSchema type would be string but it would morph it into a Temporal date.
